# Flutter | How to show AlertDialog on top of any overlay?

Tags: layout, dart, flutter, overlay

How to show AlertDialog always on top of anything on the screen?

[image]

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CountriesField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CountriesFieldState createState() => _CountriesFieldState();
}

class _CountriesFieldState extends State<CountriesField> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  OverlayEntry _overlayEntry;

  final LayerLink _layerLink = LayerLink();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
        this._overlayEntry = this._createOverlayEntry();
        Overlay.of(context).insert(this._overlayEntry);
      } else {
//        this._overlayEntry.remove();
      }
    });
  }

  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    var size = renderBox.size;

    return OverlayEntry(
        builder: (context) => Positioned(
              width: size.width,
              child: CompositedTransformFollower(
                link: this._layerLink,
                showWhenUnlinked: false,
                offset: Offset(0.0, size.height + 5.0),
                child: Material(
                  elevation: 4.0,
                  child: ListView(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Syria'),
                        onTap: () {
                          print('Syria Tapped');
                        },
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Lebanon'),
                        onTap: () {
                          print('Lebanon Tapped');
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CompositedTransformTarget(
      link: this._layerLink,
      child: Material(
        child: TextFormField(
          focusNode: this._focusNode,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Country'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class FormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FormPageState createState() => _FormPageState();
}

class _FormPageState extends State<FormPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          Material(elevation: 4.0, child: CountriesField()),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Help dialog'),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      title: Text("Help"),
                      content: Text("This should show on top of any overlay"),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        FlatButton(
                          child: Text("Close"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: un-comment your line  - `//        this._overlayEntry.remove();` - It's fine then.

Comment: @anmol.majhail I commented it intentionally because I am looking for a general answer that does not require removing the overlay entry. In some widget, it would be necessary to not destroy the overlay.

Comment: Either replace the OverlayEntry with the equivalent using Navigator. Or replace the dialog with the equivalent using OverlayEntry

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to make dialogs appear on top of overlays. Depends on your use case, you can either convert both to `Overlay`, or convert both to `Dialog`.

This is an example of converting both to dialogs, using `showDialog` method:

[image: demo]

You don't have to return an `AlertDialog` widget when showing a dialog, for example, here I'm returning a `Container` with white filling, and contains a `ListView` for the "Menu A" dialog in the back.

When using `showDialog`, you get automatic features such as dimming the background and click anywhere outside to dismiss. If you don't want these or any other dialog things, and if you cannot find a way to disable them easily, you can always go the other way around and convert both to `Overlay` instead.

For overlays, whichever gets inserted latest, is displayed on top.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a "fix", but a potential workaround for this is to basically not use Overlays and rely on a top level Stack.

If you are using Positioned in your Overlay anyway, putting your widget in a top level Stack doesn't interfere with things like Dialogs (and you potentially have more control over which areas of your app show the overlay).

Example:

```dart
class StackOverlayState extends State<StackOverlay> {
  bool _showOverlay = true; // This could also easily be a list of widgets
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: /// etc..
          ),
       ),
       if (_showOverlay)
         MyOverlayWidget(),
     ],
    );
  }
}
```

I was using Overlays, and switching to just using a Stack instead seems to have caused no issues and required no code changes in the Overlay widget itself, but YMMV.